# OnClientLoad Property in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, html

In .aspx page when we are using radcombobox and all, onclientload attribute has been used.....

To handle that OnclientLoad Handler function has been written in javascript.
**Actually what my ques is what is the use of OnclientLoad Property and OnClientLoad Handler Function in that. When it has to used. what are all the arguments it can accept... How it is working...**

This is the program i have tried

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        var rad_CatType_Id, radcb_OfferFormat, Rad_Footer;
        function OfferFormat_onClientLoadHandler(sender, args) {
            radcb_OfferFormat = sender;
        }
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">
    <table class="table_Style">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 15%">
                Select Grade Category
            </td>
            <td style="width: 20%">
                <Telerik:RadComboBox AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" ID="radcb_GradeCat" Width="165px"
                    MarkFirstMatch="true" CausesValidation="false" OnClientLoad="rad_Cattype_onClientLoadHandler">
                </Telerik:RadComboBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="cmp_cat" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select Category"
                    ValidationGroup="List" ControlToValidate="radcb_GradeCat" ValueToCompare="Select"
                    Operator="NotEqual"></asp:CompareValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>.....
```

Anyone please help me with detailed example..

Thanks in Advance.......

Answer (score 0):

The `OnClientLoad` client-side event occurs after the combobox | RadControl has been fully initialized on the client-side.

The event handler receives one parameter:
The combobox instance firing the event.

This event is helpful if you need to get the client-side instance of the combobox when it is embedded in other controls. Hook the OnClientLoad event and get the client-side instance of the combobox as demonstrated in the example below. This technique can be used to retrieve the combo instance for use elsewhere.

```
 function OnClientLoadHandler(sender)   {
        var combo;
        combo=sender;
      }

<telerik:RadComboBox 
    ID="RadComboBox1" 
    runat="server" 
    OnClientLoad="OnClientLoadHandler" .../>
```

> This technique may not work when AJAX is used. The asynchronous
>   requests may interfere with the OnClientLoad event.